# Merging 2 databases with the same structure but with some data in commom (with foreign keys to be respected but not primary keys of course)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like to merge the data from 2 databases (mysql) which have the same structure into one of the 2 databases. The 2 databases have some data in commom with foreign keys to be respected, but not the primary keys of course (the references, i.e. the foreign keys have to be respected though). What are the different (and the fastest) ways to achieve this, please?

Constraints:

- dumps generate insert lines with ids so it is problematic (since the ids are in auto-increment mode).
- the size of the databases may be 1Go each or more

Comment: Your question is very vague and cannot really be answered. As a minimum you need to tell us 1) Are we talking about syncing 2 databases with multiple tables, or just 2 tables? 2) Do the data to be synced reside in the same mysql server? This way we can describe the options, but still will not be able to tell you which is the fastes one. That depends on too many circumstances.

Comment: There are multiple tables (one in particular, but with a foreign key on an other one). The data in the referenced table are determined by their key. But the second one (the one I want to merge) no. Besides, the two databases are indeed in two different servers... If I have to, I will write a php program for example, but, is it possible to generate a script for one table but without the "id" column (which is the one with the auto increment) and inject it in the second one. Or my be, there is a simpler or smarter way. Thank you!